# Detect a Missing file based on its Date

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, server

I need to manually monitor a random windows-based backup program for failures and the only way to do this is via checking for the daily backup file it makes.

A batch file would be simplest for me to implement.  It would need to scan a directory for a certain file type and then do X if a file doesn't exist that was created/modified yesterday.

```
C:\backups\random-named-file.tib 27/03/2017
C:\backups\random-named-file.tib 28/03/2017
C:\backups\random-named-file.tib 29/03/2017
```

So if a random-named-file.tib wasnt created or modified yesterday, it means the backup failed and I would write output to the console saying "Backup Failed"

Does anyone please have any ideas ?

EDIT : 
To clarify, the backup files are coming from a custom application that has no way to check for missed backups.  The batch file solution I'm looking for will be integrated into our RMM platform, which will take the results of the batch file and raise a support desk ticket for our Service desk to action.

The backup application will apply its own retention policies and delete any backups older then 4 days.
I'm just trying to detect if a backup was missed the previous day.  The filenames are variable, the only constant is the file extension ( *.tib)

This backup app doesn't write eventlogs, nor does it create its own log files I can parse for Failure messages.

Comment: Added more info to clarify my situation.

Answer (score 0):

1) I would suggest you, go through this article

[four-ways-to-manage-windows-server-2008-backup-on-multiple-servers](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/data-center/four-ways-to-manage-windows-server-2008-backup-on-multiple-servers/)

2) There is a **windows scheduler** which can act according to your situation

[Window scheduler Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)

3) You can write scripts which alert you whenever it  fails

4) I have found a Solution for your similar kind of problem

[make-windows-task-scheduler-alert-on-fail](https://superuser.com/questions/249103/make-windows-task-scheduler-alert-me-on-fail)

TL:Dr --> see step 4

Comment: Thank you for the info, but its not applicable to my situation.  Ive added more info to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I manged to do what you asked. On a quick note, since it's Windows backup program there should be a way to automatically alert when backup fails.

Note about this example: I did this in a specific folder structure. If you want to change the location of batch file, second line of code inside batch file needs to be updated with appropriate path. In this example the path is relative, but it's easy to change, so I leave that up to you.

Here is my folder structure:

```
\---batch                          # Folder with batch file
        backups.txt                       # check_backups.bat creates this file
        check_backups.bat                 # Batch file that does the job
|   filename1.tib
|   filename2.tib
|   filename3.tib
|   filename5.tib
```

Here is the code of batch file (check_backups.bat):

```
@echo off
dir ..\* /a-d /b > "%~dp0\backups.txt"
set count=1
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "delims=*" %%A IN (backups.txt) DO (
    SET fl=%%~nA
    IF !fl:~8! NEQ !count! (
        echo Backup Failed: Missing file is 'filename!count!.tib'
        goto failed
    )
    SET /A count=!count!+1
)

echo All is good

:failed

pause
```

If filename9.tib is missing you will get a message: "Backup failed: Missing file is filename9.tib".

If everyhing is good you will get a message: "All is good".

Comment: I'm not sure this would work, as its not reading the file dates and checking for one missing on the previous day.  The number of files in my folder is variable, I need a way to check if there is no file present created on the prev day only.

Comment: @Cammo, I think I get it. I see you edited your question. I was checking for sequence based on file name. It should actually go through files and check if there is a file created yesterday?

Comment: Yes exactly, the only similarity is the file extention .tib .  The use of sequential filenames in my original example only confused the issue, so I modified my post.